# Creating "Archive" database to unload application "Main" database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, web-applications

I want to create a web application that is supposed to contain a lot of data. I want to ask if anyone of you have ever met a system that contained two databases - main and archive. I want to create a mechanism that will move old data from main database to archive database in order to unload it. For instance, when I have a table of user accounts, I want to move the ones that weren't used for, say, more than three months to an archive database. Having this done, main database may be significantly unloaded so I expect it to work faster. However such mechanism has to work in two directions - not only migrating from main to archive but also from archive to main db in order to allow user's to "refresh" their accounts. Of course in such scenario I will use GUID's instead of BIGINT's as PRIMARY KEY. What do you think about it? Is such concept right or I shouldn't bother about it and assume that there should be only one database? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Having archive database never hurts, but usually it's used for restoring or reporting. I think in most cases partitioning will serve your purpose better. Also, many RDMS systems propose different solutions out of the box, like database clustering, mirroring, etc.

Comment: Ok, so you say that it's better to add column like "IsArchive" and there exists methods/tools that will allow to clusterize the database in such way that it will operate on the records that have ("IsArchive" == false) differently (I mean optimize all SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT  queries) than on the records with "IsArchive" flag set to true? In this case I'm thinking about SQL Azure.

Comment: For instance, you can just partition table by "IsArchive" column; thus, yu will have 2 partitions (which means each of them can be stored in different physical locations); then if your queries have "IsArchive" in `WHERE` db engine will end up scanning/seeking only required partition.

Comment: Thanks - I think I will go for it!